# NextJS v12.2.0 causing Router null reference issues when running JEST tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

**The Problem**

I'm upgrading from NextJS v12.1.6 to v12.2.2 and all but one test file has upgraded successfully.

When running the `BreadcrumbTrail` test suite the test included below breaks around the routing. The issue states you cannot push to a null object; this makes sense but after debugging everything looks OK. There is a secondary issue but I believe it's a cascading problem caused by the null reference error (included anyway).

**Questions**

- Has anyone hit an error around routing in v12.2.0?
- Does anyone have a suggestion on resolving this issue?

**Basic Stack Details**

- React v18.2.0
- Next v12.2.0
- JEST v28.1.1

**Attempted Solutions/Reading**

Prior to v12.2.0 this test passed without issue.

From what I've found [PR 36660](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/36660) resolved an issue with `asPath` due to a race condition but may now be causing our current issues.

**Test Code**

```js
import { render, screen, within, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import singletonRouter from "next/router";
import mockRouter from "next-router-mock";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { BreadcrumbTrail } from "./BreadcrumbTrail";

jest.mock("next/dist/client/router", () => require("next-router-mock"));

const navPath = "/some-navpath";

describe("BreadcrumbTrail", function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRouter.setCurrentUrl(navPath);
  });

  it("navigates to the correct location when clicking on a crumb", async function () {
    render(<BreadcrumbTrail />);
    const breadcrumbs = screen.getByRole("list", { name: /breadcrumbs/i });
    const { getByText } = within(breadcrumbs);
    const breadcrumb = getByText("Foo");

    await userEvent.click(breadcrumb);

    await waitFor(() =>
      expect(singletonRouter).toMatchObject({
        asPath: "/someother-navpath",
      }),
    );
  });
});
```

**Error One**

```
FAIL  components/Navigation/BreadcrumbTrail.test.tsx

Console

 console.error
   Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null]

...
...
...

EventTarget.js:241:34)
   at dispatchEvent (/<Repository Path>/node_modules/@testing-library/user-event/dist/index.cjs:1716:33)
   at /<Repository Path>/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:125:16
   at /<Repository Path>/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:110:24
   at act (/<Repository Path>/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:2457:20) {
     detail: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
        at navigate (/<Repository Path>/node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:90:11)
        at linkClicked (/<Repository Path>/node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:100:5)
        at onClick (/<Repository Path>/node_modules/next/dist/client/link.js:330:9)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/<Repository Path>/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:730:119)

...
...
...

BreadcrumbTrail › navigates to the correct location when clicking on a crumb

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null

      40 |     const breadcrumb = getByText("Foo");
      41 |
    > 42 |     await userEvent.click(breadcrumb);
```

**Error Two**

```
expect(received).toMatchObject(expected)

- Expected  - 1
+ Received  + 1

Object {
-   "asPath": "/someother-navpath",
+   "asPath": "/some-navpath",
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a problem within [next-router-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-router-mock); this package has broken due to significant changes in how routing is managed in NextJS.

Source: [Issue with next/link in Next 12.2.0](https://github.com/scottrippey/next-router-mock/issues/58)

The following code should fix the issue

```js
jest.mock("next/dist/client/router", () => require("next-router-mock"));

jest.mock("next/dist/shared/lib/router-context", () => {
  const { createContext } = require("react");
  const router = require("next-router-mock").default;
  const RouterContext = createContext(router);
  return { RouterContext };
});
```

Comment: Woks very nicly.
But I needed to reset the mock in in the before each hook